# Angular date filter: Format month as local time

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime-format, datefilter

I have a date formatted as a ISO-8601 string: `overview.startTime = "2017-05-09T08:00:00Z"`

I want to display this on my page and I have used the following code:

```
Dagens arbetspass {{overview.startTime | date:'dd-MMM'}}
```

This is displayed as "Dagens arbetspass 09-May". My problem is that this is a Swedish site, and in Sweden we don't start the month names with an uppercase character. Also May is written "maj" (j in the end and not y). I tried to add the timezone like this

```
Dagens arbetspass {{overview.startTime | date:'dd-MMM':'Europe/Stockholm'}}
```

but that did not change the output. In fact, most months are spelled differently in Swedish. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the javascript "toLocaleDateString" method to resolve the concern. The method takes two arguments which are 'locale' and 'options'.

Locale will be "sv-se" for swedish.

Options will provide the format to your string. For example -`var options = { weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month:long",day:"numeric" };`

```
var d = new Date("2017-05-09T08:00:00Z");
date.toLocaleDateString("sv-se", options)
```

Here's a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/G2IL5Zv0OAcVRMZS9HB7

Comment: little caveat: When a user with a different locale (let's say, czech) visits the site they will see swedish dates / day names. The regular `DatePipe` of Angular uses `Intl` and respects the user's browser / OS settings.